# Local storage/Cookie in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, local-storage

On NODE JS I'm running 3 apps at 3 different ports,
Lets take them as at ports 3000,3007,3005.

Now my aim is I want to set a Localstorage/Cookie variable at port 3000 and want to get this local storage value at the apps running at port 3005 and port 3007.

And My folder structure is:

```
   nodep/
         |-app.js(runs at 3000 port)
         |-chat2.js(runs at 3005 port)
         |-chat3.js(runs at 3007 port)
```

How can I achieve this.

Comment: LocalStorage/Coookies are stored in browser. So node.js has nothing to do with it. I guess all you need is cross-domain access to localStorage/Cookies.

Comment: Are you using any http-server framework library ? like express.

Comment: @alexeyten your guess is right

Comment: @user568109 no I'm not using http-server frame work

Comment: @ManoharGunturu Can you elaborate your statement `I want to set a Localstorage/Cookie variable at port 3000`?

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni  I want to store a value in varibale present in 3000 and want to get that value at port 3005 and 3007 ports

Answer (score 0):

for reading/setting cookies server side you need some HTTP-server. you also should use a [Cookie-Module](https://npmjs.org/package/cookies), because it makes it easier.

your code would look like this:

```
var http = require('http'),
    Cookies = require('cookies');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   var cookies = new Cookies(request, response);

   // get a cookie value
   cookies.get('yourCookieKey');

   // set a cookie value
   cookies.set('yourCookieKey', 'yourCookieValue');

   response.end(200);
});
```

Keep in mind, that there are Browsers and Settings in some Browsers out there which deny 3rd-party cookies.

Reading/Setting Values from/in the localStorage are just not possible.

What you really want to do is probably some "data-exchange" between your client (browser) and your server (your app.js).

For that to work you could use

a) AJAX, and probably send/receive some JSON data

or

b) use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for sending that data. socket.io has the advantage of working cross-domain.

in both cases you could of course store/restore/sync the data with the localStorage

there is some last option, if you really want some rich-data client, which is [breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com/) this would provide you some client-side "Database" which could be synced with a server-side rest api. but i don't think thats what you want...

hope that helped a little, your question was kind of unclear/confusing...